# How to initialize ArrayList

Tags: java, bluej

I have a Very basic question.
How do I need to type parrameters for ArrayList to use the code in BlueJ?
I have a method as below.

`public void requiresVaccination(int year, ArrayList<Cat>list)`

I have created some cat objects cat1, cat2 and cat3.

I thought, I need to type `2012` for the`year`and `[cat1, cat2, cat3]` for the ArrayList but obiusly I am wrong.
Could anyone tell me what I need to do, please?

Answer (score 1):

To invoke the method, pass the year together with a new ArrayList object.

Using *double brace initialization*, the code for the second argument becomes:

```
new ArrayList<Cat>() {{ add(cat1); add(cat2); add(cat3); }};
```

To call the method, use:

```
requiresVaccination(2012, new ArrayList<Cat>() {{ add(cat1); add(cat2); add(cat3); }});
```

I think this is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the method a list of Cat Objects, you can't do what you are suggesting.

Comment: Hmm, okay then. Will change it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible to use a signature like this

```
public void requiresVaccination(int year, Cat... list)
```

therefore you can call your methode something like this

```
 requiresVaccination(2010, cat1, cat2, cat3);
```

and inside function it is possible to behave with list like an array of Cat (Cat[])

Comment: Sorry I am confused still so if I want to test my code. I need to create method call is that right? Then how do I call my method? and how can I use a debugger in BlueJ.